# Linux Command to search for text in particular file

Tags: linux, string, ssh, command

I need a little help. Basically, I am trying to search a text string in wordpress theme files.

That string is located in wp-content/themes/style.css.

So basically I am trying to search a string in all style.css files on all wordpress installations of home directory.

Is it possible to search all style.css files only and if the string is found display it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...

Search for PATTERN in each FILE or standard input.

PATTERN is, by default, a basic regular expression (BRE).

Example: grep -i 'hello world' menu.h main.c

Answer (score 0):

Use grep to search for text inside files.

> grep -rniw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e 'pattern'

- -r or -R is recursive,
- -n is line number, and
- -i - case insensitive search
- -w stands for match the whole word.
- -l (lower-case L) can be added to just give the file name of    matching files.

For you case, use:

```
grep -rniw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e 'wp-content/themes/style.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands:

cd /home/

find . -iname "*.css" -exec grep -l "text_string" {} +

Do not forget to replace text_string with the actual text string.